# Choosing interpolation method for monthly atmospheric parameters derived from AQUA/Air satellite?

Tags: interpolation, kriging, nearest-neighbor, text, spline

I want to investigate **atmospheric refraction** and i am using Aqua/ Airs satellite data. These are atmospheric parameters

(1) Air temperature

(2) Geopotential height

(3) Relative Humidity

All these parameters are at different pressure levels (1000, 925,800,....1 hpa). It is Aqua/AIRS version 6 level 3 product. Please suggest me which interpolation technique will be best suited for this data sets? This data set is in text format.

I have these softwares : ArcGIS 9.3, Erdas,Envi, Matlab etc suggest also other software which can also assist me in text file data.

Comment: What aspect of atmospheric refraction are you investigating? That is, what question are you trying to answer?

Comment: @ BradHards thank you so much for contribution. Actually i am going to investigate anomalous propagation using this data set. My above mentioned parameters are associated with this propagation. This data set is on different atmospheric pressure levels. That why i want to know about more best interpolation for missing data. This is monthly mean data set.

Comment: Interpolation techniques like : Nearest neighbor, Bilinear interpolation, spline, kringing which will be best for this data set?